# Setting 100% height on "html" element does not work…

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have this 100% height probelm

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dreamweaver Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<section class="intro">
<div class="inner">
<div class="content">
<h1>Breath Easy</h1>
<a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
</div>

</div>

</section>

<p>
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', 
a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it 
   has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 
'Content here, content here', 
</p>

   </body>
   </html>
```

and here is the css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


@import url{'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway'};
@import url{'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'};

html,body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.intro{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: #DF1E21;
}
```

why its not showing full height. by the way I'm following this tutorial video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5SHm53WFEk&index=2&list=PLzSW4vYtPmwL4c2XB5kFMWNM8ABNvYArX

Comment: Its working fine https://jsfiddle.net/1voud5a2/1/ and there is one extra `\p` tag in your code check that(but this not effects your issue).

Comment: but it's not showing in the live-preview or in chrome.

Comment: Is it working as you expected in fiddle i have shared in my last comment?

Comment: One issue I can see in the fiddle is a block of white at the top of the page. Is that the problem? This is caused by the margin to the H1.

Comment: @Znaneswar it's working in fiddle but not the live-preview of dreamweaver or in chrome here is screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/lM6mN

Comment: Please create fiddle with your code and share

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/2y52yhyp/

Comment: Never mind the problem is with dreamweaver itself not saving correctly

Comment: @KadiemHaider its because syntax error in your code please check my answer below  if it works please accept it as answer

Comment: its not the problem of dreamweaver there is syntax error in your code see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error in your `@import` font files replace `{` and `}` with `(` and `)` respectively.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2y52yhyp/1/)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');

html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  
}

.intro {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  background:gold;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dreamweaver Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<section class="intro">
<div class="inner">
<div class="content">
<h1>Breath Easy</h1>
<a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

100% block .intro section - shall cover whole container plus you have some additional text underneath it - not clear where that thext shall go. 100% + something?

Solution:

move that additional text into .intro section:

```css
html,body {
  margin:0;padding:0;
  height:100%;
  
}

.intro {
  margin:0;padding:0;
  height:100%;
  background:gold;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dreamweaver Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<section class="intro">
<div class="inner">
<div class="content">
<h1>Breath Easy</h1>
<a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
</div>
</div>
<p>
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', 
</p>
a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it 
   has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 
'Content here, content here', 
</p>
</section>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" button above. Is it still not working?

Comment: Yes it's working when I click Run code snippet but in chrome no here is screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/lM6mN

Comment: Are you testing  "Run code snippet"  in Chrome too?

Comment: I only use chrome so yes

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes an identical result of what's shown in the video.
What exactly is your "100% height problem"?

I believe your solution is to be patient and keep watching...

Comment: Here is screenshot of the webpage in chrome https://imgur.com/a/lM6mN as you can see it's not occupying the whole height of the screen.

Comment: @KadiemHaider interesting. Pressing F12, do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Never mind the problem is with dreamweaver itself not saving correctly. thanks for the help